Macos application's auto login is not working
I have created a authentication-plugin for my macosX application. i have added the outfile.plist as per the [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NameAndPassword/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004022][1]
now after changed the outfile.plist and security authentication db screensaver not my application is not working as expected(auto-login is not working.) and it stuck with screensaver. After manual restart the system,i can able to do any operations. please help me on this.
Thanks
